# How to change color in one tr in a table on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>A4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>B3</td>
            <td>B4</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I'm wondering if I can click a cell and change the color (with a class):

```
.selected
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

If I click on A1:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="selected">A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>A4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>B3</td>
            <td>B4</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

And then I click on A3, it will be like this

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td class="selected">A3</td>
            <td>A4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>B3</td>
            <td>B4</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

What i have done

```
<style>
        .hover
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .select
        {
            background-color: green;
        }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("td").mouseover(function()
            {
                $(this).addClass("hover");
            });
            $("td").mouseleave(function()
            {
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
            });
            $("td").click(function()
            {
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
                $(this).addClass("select");
            });
        });
</script>
```

I'm wondering how to do that using JQuery. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but have you even searched for a way of doing it?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$('table td').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('table').find('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>D2</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>D4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's worth noting (not sure if it's appropriate given the limited info in the OP though), that this will not support multiple tables. It will remove the `selected` class from ALL tables.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like below:-

```js
$('table tr td').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('table').find('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td class="selected">A2</td>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>A4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>B4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>A5</td>
      <td class="selected">A6</td>
      <td>A7</td>
      <td>A8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>B5</td>
      <td>B6</td>
      <td>B7</td>
      <td>B8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `on()` and `addClass()` functions, for example:

```js
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {  
    $(this).parents('table').find('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>A4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>B3</td>
            <td>B4</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please could the DV be explained?

Comment: That´s the best solution while only one event handler is bound to table and and the event only needs to bubble up one level .

Answer (score 1):

The 4 lines in jQuery

```
$('td').click(function(){
  $('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

Add an event Listener to the row.

remove the previous element's class

add the class to clicked element

```js
$('td').click(function(){
  $('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see the other answers. The click and class should be bound to `td`, not `tr`.

Comment: Ok. But I noticed the title. will change it

Comment: I edited and then working in the snippet. when returned, I saw 3 answers added. But I don't want to waste my effort

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('table').find('td.selected').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this also. It will be used for individual row

```
$('table td').click(function() {
$(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
});
```